# jQuery binding function on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a little plugin for jQuery and so far I've got this:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.extend({

        someFunction: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var obj = $(this);
                obj.focus(someInternalFunction(obj));
            });
        }

    });

    function someInternalFunction(obj) {
    };

})(jQuery);
```

The problem is, when i attach someFunction to the object, the object gets focus and binding of someInternalFunction on focus event fails.

Then I tried to bind function to wrap the function call in the other function:

```
obj.focus(function() {
    someInternalFunction($(this));
});
```

This code works, but it isn't pretty at all. Is it possible to bind function on focus without wrapping it in the other function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.fn.bindFocus() = function(){
    var internalFunction = function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            self = this;
        // try do stuff here
    };
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).bind('focus', internalFunction);
    });
}

$('#myElement').bindFocus();
```

Hope it'll help ?

EDT. Sorry, first time get you wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
obj.focus(someInternalFunction(obj));
                              ^^^^^
```

... you're *calling* the function, meaning that its return value is the thing that actually ends up being passed to **`focus()`**. Instead you want to pass a function to **`focus()`**. Given the fact that you want to pass **`obj`** to **`someInternalFunction`**, you'll have to define an additional function to wrap it all:

```
obj.focus(function(){
    someInternalFunction(obj);
});
```

Just to make things clear:

```
var x = function() { return 3; }; // Defining a function

x; // -> this is a function reference
x(); // -> this is 3
```

Comment: Oh... Well... Talk about embarrassing.
Seriously, though, thanks for pointing out my mistake.
Now I shall try to come up with a number of excuses on why I thought that a function call was equal to a function reference.